# Year string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date

I am totally new to javascript and I have a very easy to answer question: How do I use a current year string?

Should I look like this?

```
var currentyear = now.getYear();
```

And then I want to use that string in the following code snippet (The string should always replace the 2011)

```
drawDayEvents('2011-12-27', '#day1');
drawDayEvents('2011-12-28', '#day2');
drawDayEvents('2011-12-29', '#day3');
drawDayEvents('2011-12-30', '#day4');

...

var start = new Date(2011, 12-1, 27);
var end = new Date(2011, 12-1, 31);
if((time < start) || (time > end)) {
time.setYear(2011);
```

Does it has to be like this?

```
var currentyear = now.getYear();

drawDayEvents('$currentyear-12-27', '#day1');
drawDayEvents('$currentyear-12-28', '#day2');
drawDayEvents('$currentyear-12-29', '#day3');
drawDayEvents('$currentyear-12-30', '#day4');

...

var start = new Date($currentyear, 12-1, 27);
var end = new Date($currentyear, 12-1, 31);
if((time < start) || (time > end)) {
time.setYear($currentyear);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `getFullYear()` instead because `getYear()` will return the year minus 1900.

```
var currentyear = now.getFullYear();
```

In this line:

```
drawDayEvents('$currentyear-12-27', '#day1');
```

JavaScript can't interpolate variables like PHP can.  You need to concat the strings.

```
drawDayEvents(currentyear+'-12-27', '#day1');
```

Variables in JavaScript don't need to be prefixed with `$` (they *can* contain a `$` if you want).

```
var start = new Date(currentyear, 12-1, 27);
var end = new Date(currentyear, 12-1, 31);
if((time < start) || (time > end)) {
  time.setYear(currentyear);
}
```

Docs for JavaScript Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: var currentyear = now.getFullYear(); ? is $currentyear right or not?

Comment: `now` isn't a keyword either.

Comment: `time` is not declared, either. Suppose that and `now` should be clarified.

Comment: @MichealPerr: No, `$currentyear` is not right.  It's just `currentyear`, you don't need the `$`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm assuming that `time` and `now` were declared earler.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I'm assuming he declared `now` earlier.

Comment: How do I found out the current year then when time and now isn't a keyword at all? No they weren't dclared earler I have no idea what I am doing :D

Comment: @MichealPerr: I figured you declared `now` earlier, if not do `var now = new Date;`.

Comment: @AdamRackis: There are different methods you can use to get the parts of the date you want.  Take a look at the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2

Comment: @AdamRackis: `Date.now()` returns you the current [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  You can add and subtract this to Date objects.  So, `var time = Date.now()` will get the current time.

Comment: @MichealPerr: Yeah, the JavaScript Date object is confusing.  That's why I suggest using a library, like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: No I know - I just now saw your comment saying you're assuming now was declared earlier.

Comment: @MichealPerr - See a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RDzZC/ Note, you'll need Firebug or Chrome console open to see the output.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: You should log `time.toString()`.

Answer (score 11):

You can get the year like this:

```
var yr = new Date().getFullYear();
```

then use the + (string concatenation) operator to join it to another string:

```
drawDayEvents(yr + "-12-27", "#day1");
```